# Подскажите как подавить ошибку Context has been deprecated (контекст устарел)

Tags: java, android

Механизм вибрации усовершенствовали но я по прежнему его использую на старых устройствах.
Как мне отключить уведомления об ошибках. Если мне нужно использовать этот старый код.
Я слышал что можно где-то прописать чего-то

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

..
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
MainActivity.java:154: warning: [deprecation] VIBRATOR_SERVICE in Context has been deprecated
            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

MainActivity.java:160: warning: [deprecation] VIBRATOR_SERVICE in Context has been deprecated
            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

MainActivity.java:161: warning: [deprecation] vibrate(long) in Vibrator has been deprecated
            vibrator.vibrate(50);
```

Comment: Warning это не ошибка, а предупреждение.

Answer (score 0):

У себя использую проверку на версию Android:

```
vibrator = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
    val vibratorManager =
        getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_MANAGER_SERVICE) as VibratorManager
    vibratorManager.defaultVibrator
} else {
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
}
```

Вот [документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator) по данному вопросу